# Increase the size of subscript in math mode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize, subscripts

I would like to add the size of the subscript p_i in the math form here:

```
    $loc_{p_i}$
```

Comment: Please tell us which font family you use.

Comment: @Mico: thanks for the reply. It's an IEEEtran confrence paper. i do not know the font family.

Answer (score 3):

In the formula `$loc_{p_i}$`, the character `i` is rendered in `scriptscriptstyle`. In contrast, in the formula `${loc_p}_i$`, the `i` rendered in `scriptstyle`. (`p` is rendered in `scriptstyle` in both formulas.) I assume it's `${loc_p}_i$` you're looking for.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$loc_{p_i}$ vs.\ ${loc_p}_i$
\end{document}
```

Syntactically, the two formulas are not quite the same: in the first formula, `p_i` is a subscript to `loc`, whereas in the second `i` is a subscript to `loc_p`.